# How to draw three box plot for each job title in each year from 2020,2021,2022(no makie package)?

Tags: julia, vega-lite, julia-plots

I have got this dataset:
[image]

and so far I have draw this:
[image]

[image]

I need to draw three box plot for each job title to represent the different work year from 2020,2021,2022,no makie package cause somehow my computer can't install it, can someone please give me some advices?
Thanks!

Comment: Please take these advices seriously: 1️⃣[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2️⃣[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).